# Using Qt Designer to Create a Form in QGIS that can search for a specific point in a layer

Tags: qgis, layers, spatial-database, query, qt-designer

I would like to ask if you can create a form in Qt Designer to create a form that can search for a point on the map using data that the user will provide such as the Name.

I am currently creating a map in QGIS for my school project and i was thinking if i can create a form that can search the layer for a specific point and show the result in a dialog box using Qt Designer.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the "Quick Finder" plugin available on the official QGIS plugin repository (Plugins > Manage and install plugins...). It sounds like this will do what you need.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have much experience with [PyQt](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro), I would suggest that you use the [QGIS Plugin Builder plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/pluginbuilder/) to get you started. This will generate a basic plugin structure including UI which you can then modify using Qt Designer to suit your purpose. You would need to write a bit of Python to carry out the 'search for a point on the map using data that the user will provide'.

Alternatively, the [Quickfinder plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/quickfinder/) may do what your asking (or take a look at the source to get you started).